# Create a 3D Array Opinion System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two Characters 'Alisha' and 'John' who have an opinion between them of 30. But what I really want to achieve is Alisha have an opinon of john 20 and John has an Opinion of Alisha 20. In short, create a 3D Array to solve the problem.

I have created two Scriptable Objects 'Character' and 'OpinionsTable' with an opinion array. I have mostly achieved what I want to. The code of mine is working perfectly for Characters like for example. I have also created an editor script creating a opinion matrix but I want to enhance it to a 3D Matrix.

Character.cs

```
 using UnityEngine;

 [CreateAssetMenu()]
 public class Character : ScriptableObject
 {
     public string Name;
 }
```

OpinionsTable.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu()]
public class OpinionsTable : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Character[] characters;

    [SerializeField]
    private int[] opinions;

    public int this[int i, int j] // Where i and j are indices of characters in the array above
    {
        get { return opinions[i * characters.Length + j]; }
        set { opinions[i * characters.Length + j] = value; }
    }
}
```

OpinionsTableEditor.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor( typeof( OpinionsTable ) )]
public class OpinionsTableEditor : Editor
{
    const float opinionsLabelWidth = 50;
    const float opinionCellSize = 25;
    SerializedProperty characters;
    SerializedProperty opinions;
    int opinionsTableWidth = 0;
    Rect opinionsTableRect;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        // Retrieve the serialized properties
        characters = serializedObject.FindProperty( "characters" );
        opinions = serializedObject.FindProperty( "opinions" );
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        // Check if the number of characters has been changed
        // If so, resize the opinions
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField( characters, true );
        if( EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck() )
        {
            opinions.arraySize = characters.arraySize * characters.arraySize;
        }

        // Draw opinions if there is more than one character
        if ( opinions.arraySize > 1 )
            DrawOpinions( opinions, characters );
        else
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField( "Not enough characters to draw opinions matrix" );

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void DrawOpinions( SerializedProperty opinions, SerializedProperty characters )
    {
        int charactersCount = characters.arraySize;
        if ( Event.current.type == EventType.Layout )
            opinionsTableWidth = Mathf.FloorToInt( EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth );

        // Get the rect of the whole matric, labels included
        Rect rect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(opinionsTableWidth, opinionsTableWidth, EditorStyles.inspectorDefaultMargins);

        if ( opinionsTableWidth > 0 && Event.current.type == EventType.Repaint )
            opinionsTableRect = rect;

        // Draw matrix and labels only if the rect has been computed
        if( opinionsTableRect.width > 0 )
        {
            // Compute size of opinion cell
            float cellWidth     = Mathf.Min( (opinionsTableRect.width - opinionsLabelWidth) / charactersCount, opinionCellSize );
            Rect opinionCell    = new Rect( opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth, opinionsTableRect.y + opinionsLabelWidth, cellWidth, cellWidth );
            Matrix4x4 guiMatrix = GUI.matrix;

            // Draw vertical labels
            for ( int i = 1 ; i <= charactersCount ; ++i )
             {
                 Rect verticalLabelRect = new Rect( opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + i * opinionCell.width, opinionsTableRect.y, opinionsLabelWidth, opinionsLabelWidth );
                 Character character = characters.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i - 1 ).objectReferenceValue as Character;
                 EditorGUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot( 90f, new Vector2( verticalLabelRect.x, verticalLabelRect.y ) );
                 EditorGUI.LabelField( verticalLabelRect, character == null ? "???" : character.Name );
                 GUI.matrix = guiMatrix;
             }            

             // Draw matrix
             for ( int i = 0 ; i < charactersCount ; ++i )
             {
                 // Draw horizontal labels
                 SerializedProperty characterProperty = characters.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i );
                 Character character = characterProperty == null ? null : characters.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i ).objectReferenceValue as Character;
                 EditorGUI.LabelField( new Rect( opinionsTableRect.x, opinionCell.y, opinionsLabelWidth, opinionCell.height ), character == null ? "???" : character.Name ) ;

                 for ( int j = 0 ; j < charactersCount ; ++j )
                 {
                     opinionCell.x = opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + j * cellWidth;
                     if ( j > i )
                     {
                         SerializedProperty opinion = opinions.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i * charactersCount + j );
                         opinion.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField( opinionCell, opinion.intValue );
                     }
                     else // Put grey box because the matrix is symmetrical
                     {
                         EditorGUI.DrawRect( opinionCell, Color.grey );
                     }
                 }
                 opinionCell.y += cellWidth; 
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I got the matrix all right and I can also set the values for two characters.

[image]

But what I want to achieve that two Characters should have two opinions between them like Opinion of a for b and b for a. It would be also nice if you can provide a way to store the value of one opinion to another int.

Comment: So what is your actual question about? `But what I want to achieve that two Characters should have two opinions between them like Opinion of a for b and b for a. It would be also nice if you can provide a way to store the value of one opinion to another int.` that sure might be nice but can you show how you tried to implement that? And narrow the question down a bit ... e.g. is your editor script really relevant code if your question is actually about the data structure/functionality itself?

Comment: I want to extend the code a bit further. Like as you can see from the picture that James and Alice have an opinion of 2 about them. But what I want to achieve is that James will have an opinion of Alice, that is 2 but Alice will also have an opinion about James (say 4). This is possible by adding Alice in the third element but I do not like duplicating items, especially in Unity. This question was posted by me in UNITY Answers and yes, this code works. Another answer I want to get from my question is how can I store one opinion int (say that James to Alice, 2) to another int through script.

Comment: This seems relevant `else // Put grey box because the matrix is symmetrical`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already answered [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1617261/how-to-create-an-opinion-system-between-characters.html), you don't need the 3D array, you simply need to allow the full matrix to be edited :

Sure, but you don't need a 3D array. You just have to allow the bottom-left side of the matrix to be edited :

```
for ( int j = 0 ; j < charactersCount ; ++j )
{
    opinionCell.x = opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + j * cellWidth;
    if ( j > i )
    {
        SerializedProperty opinion = opinions.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i * charactersCount + j );
        opinion.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField( opinionCell, opinion.intValue );
    }
    else // Put grey box because the matrix is symmetrical
    {
        EditorGUI.DrawRect( opinionCell, Color.grey );
    }
}
```

Must be replaced by

```
for ( int j = 0 ; j < charactersCount ; ++j )
{
    opinionCell.x = opinionsTableRect.x + opinionsLabelWidth + j * cellWidth;
    SerializedProperty opinion = opinions.GetArrayElementAtIndex( i * charactersCount + j );
    opinion.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField( opinionCell, opinion.intValue );
}
```